# Добавление в БД сущности с первичным ключом

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Добрый день! 
У меня есть сущность Teacher:

```
public class Teacher
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Teacher()
    {

    }

    public Teacher(string name, string login, string password)
    {
        Name = name;
        Login = login;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь добавить новую запись следующим образом:

```
public class JournalContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    public JournalContext()
        : base("name=JournalContext1")
    {

    }

    public void AddTeacher(string name, string login, string password)
    {
        Teachers.Add(new Teacher(name, login, password));

        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Но когда я пытаюсь выполнить метод:

```
using (JournalContext context = new JournalContext())
{
    context.AddTeacher("Name", "Login", "Password");
}
```

генерируется исключение:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Login', table 'JournalClass.JournalContext.dbo.Teachers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Хотя все данные считываются верно. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public string Login { get; set; }
```

Тут вы указываете, чтобы в таблице первичным ключом выступало поле типа string и при этом просите, чтобы генерировалось число (автоинкремент - Identity).

**Можно поступить 2-мя способами:**

**1.** Убрать автоинкремент у `Login` и установить уникальный индекс. Тогда автогенерация не будет использоваться:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string Login { get; set; }
```

**2.** Сделать первичным ключом `Id` с автоинкрементом, а поле `Login` просто уникальным:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public string Login { get; set; }
```

Comment: Нет смысла использовать `Index(IsUnique = true)` в первом случае - первичный ключ сам по себе является индексом.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, очевидно, в том, что [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Представляет шаблон, используемый для формирования значений для свойства в базе данных.
>   База данных формирует значение при вставке строки.

А Вы пытаетесь вставить туда своё значение. Ну и поле **Identity** должно быть типа **int**, а не **string**.

Comment: *Ну и поле Identity должно быть типа int, а не string.* - не обязательно. Точнее, зависит от схемы БД. Если EF Code First не умеет создавать Identity-поля на строках - это еще не значит что EF Code First не поддерживает такие поля.